# remove class from container parent class with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to remove and add class container parent class with jQuery?
i want to remove blueContent when i click cardTab2 and add greenContent

```
<div class="mainContent blueContent">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="cardBox">
            <ul class="cardButton nav nav-tabs">
                <li role="presentation" class="cardSelect cardTab1 active">
                    <a href="#cardTab1" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><img src="images/smartCard.png" /><span>Smart Payout Card</span></a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="cardSelect cardTab2">
                    <a href="#cardTab2" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><img src="images/card2.png" /><span>Achiever Card</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
(function($) {
  $('.cardTab1 , .cardTab2').bind('click', function() { 
  if($(this).hasClass('cardTab1')) {
     $('cardTab1').parents('.mainContent').removeClass('.greenContent');
      $('cardTab1').parents('.mainContent').addClass('.buleContent');
  } else if($(this).hasClass('cardTab2')) {
    $('cardTab1').parents('.mainContent').removeClass('.buleContent');
    $('cardTab1').parents('.mainContent').addClass('.greenContent');
  }
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: missing `.` before class selector

Comment: `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` just take class names, not selectors, so there's no need to prefix the class names with a `.` - eg. `.removeClass("greenContent");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `.` to class selectors and remove `.` from `removeClass()` and `addClass()` methods:

```
(function($) {
  $('.cardTab1 , .cardTab2').bind('click', function() { 
  if($(this).hasClass('cardTab1')) {
     $('.cardTab1').parents('.mainContent').removeClass('greenContent');
      $('.cardTab1').parents('.mainContent').addClass('buleContent');
  } else if($(this).hasClass('cardTab2')) {
    $('.cardTab2').parents('.mainContent').removeClass('buleContent');
    $('.cardTab2').parents('.mainContent').addClass('greenContent');
  }
});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use this code actually u don't use class selector properly

```js
(function($) {
  $('.cardTab1 , .cardTab2').bind('click', function() { 
  if($(this).hasClass('cardTab1')) {
     $('.cardTab1').parents('.mainContent').removeClass('greenContent');
      $('.cardTab1').parents('.mainContent').addClass('buleContent');
  } else if($(this).hasClass('cardTab2')) {
    $('.cardTab2').parents('.mainContent').removeClass('buleContent');
    $('.cardTab2').parents('.mainContent').addClass('greenContent');
  }
});
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainContent blueContent">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="cardBox">
            <ul class="cardButton nav nav-tabs">
                <li role="presentation" class="cardSelect cardTab1 active">
                    <a href="#cardTab1" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><img src="images/smartCard.png" /><span>Smart Payout Card</span></a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" class="cardSelect cardTab2">
                    <a href="#cardTab2" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><img src="images/card2.png" /><span>Achiever Card</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```